# How to load javascript files in the swift repl

Tags: swift, read-eval-print-loop

I would like to load some javascript files into the `Swift` REPL.  How can that be done?  My attempt is launching

```
swift
```

from a directory containing the javascript files and then executing

```
import Foundation
let js = "jquery.min"
if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: js, withExtension: "js") {
    print("found \(js)")
} else {
    print("Try another day")
}
```

Naturally we see

> Try another day

Is there any way to load resources/files in the REPL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have expanded the code as follows:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

func getResources(_ subDir:String? = nil, _ ext: String? = nil)->[URL]? {
    return Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: ext, subdirectory: subDir)
}

let furls: String = {
    if let fileURLs = getResources(nil, nil) {
    print(fileURLs)
    return("found \(fileURLs.map{$0.absoluteString}.joined(separator: "\n"))")
} else {
    return("Try another day")
}
}()
```

The point here is to see exactly what are the files in the playground. Apparently *none of the project files are included*

So there would be no way to access the `.js` files - or any other ones for that matter.  This is in contrast to say `scala` repl that has full access to the enclosing project.

[image]